# Insert object on parse in my table

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, pfquery

I have a view controller with inside table and I want to fill her with an array saved on Parse. To download the data I use this code:

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"myClass"];
[query whereKey:@"X" equalTo:@"Y"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if(error==nil){

       myArray=[object objectForKey:@"Z"];
       NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
    }

}];
}
```

Now I display it inside `myarray` the data on parse. But if I use arrays to populate the table it is always me empty. I used `NSLog` and I saw that outside of the method `[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock: ^ (PFObject * object, NSError * error)` my array is always empty.
How can help me?

Comment: You are getting back just first object found from Parse, not an array. You should probably use different method for fetching data from Parse?

Comment: Have you maybe taken a look at their example: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-powered-ios-table-views/ ?

Comment: You know the method that I can use? thanks

Comment: Please clarify.  Does `NSLog(@"%@",myArray);` within the completion block show expected values?  Certainly an NSLog after the block (which runs before the getFirst completes *should* show that it is uninitialized.

Comment: This example uses a table controller, but I have a table within a view controller so no good for me

Comment: this is result of NSLog:                                                                      2015-04-17 15:56:19.621     myApp[20272:1164923] (
    "test1",
    "test2"
)

Comment: @GianlucaCarpi - great result.  Use that array as datasource for the table, and *within* the completion block say `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: But if i use NSLog outside to method getFirstObjectInBackgroudWithBlock the result is null.

Comment: I can't use it in the datasource table because I found the empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching data from a remote database takes a little time.  The parse functions that take block params run asynchronously.  See the comments within your slightly modified code...

```
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if(error==nil){
       // this appears first in the file, but runs later
       // after the request is finished
       myArray=[object objectForKey:@"Z"];
       NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
       // tell our view that data is ready
       [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];

// this appears second in the file, but runs right away, right
// when the request is started
// while execution is here, the request isn't done yet
// we would expect myArray to be uninitialized
```

Be sure, in your datasource methods e.g. `numberOfRows` to answer `myArray.count`.  And use the data in the array `myArray[indexPath.row]` when building the table view cell.